# I have been using the EPSG4326 coordinate system continuously. The x and y coordinates flipped. What happened?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have been using the EPSG4326 coordinate system continuously for 2 months in QGIS, alongside Google Maps in QuickMapServices. I recently discovered the given coordinates are flipped, i.e. "22. 114" becomes "114, 22". What happened? How do I revert it back? And how do I know which coordinate is the right one?

I am quite new to GIS.

Comment: The correct order for coordinates in EPSG:4326 is lat/long. For any CRS where EPSG is the authority you can check their registry (epsg.org) to see which axis order is correct.  So for (CRS) EPSG:4326 there's https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html